# How to keep a timer running when app is minised or in the background (C# Windows 10 universal app)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I previously created a timer and stopwatch app for Windows Phone 8.1, but it does not run in the background or behind lockscreens. I am currently updating this for windows 10 universal app and could do with some help to implement these features.

Comment: Consider using a background thread if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be tempting to try do this in a background task, but that is very heavy-handed, for a simple problem.

What I would suggest is to record a DateTime of when they started recording:

```
DateTime _startDateTime;
void Start()
{
_startDateTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Then do your regular timing code (presumably with a `DispatcherTimer`) which will run a method every x milliseconds:

```
void UpdateTime()
{
TimeSpan totalTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_startDateTime);
// Update UI
}
```

Now, if the user minimizes the app, code will stop running, however when you return, the math in `UpdateTime()` is using an absolute value of `_startDateTime` so it doesn't matter if you were minimized for an hour or a week - as soon as `UpdateTime()` runs it will correctly work out the elapsed time. 
Unless they minimize and change the time on the phone, but there really isn't much you can do about that ;-).

Comment: that works very well for the stopwatch side of the app but it also has another option as a count down which sets an alarm off when it reaches zero, do you have any suggestions for that or do you believe that would have to be a background task

Comment: The problem with a background task is that they are only allowed to run for a limited amount of time, and only every so often. As a work-around you could try creating a background audio task (which runs continually), and just not play any music in it. I'm not 100% sure if that would work though, or if you can do things like toasts from there.

Comment: Instead of using `DateTime.Now`, you can use `DateTie.UtcNow` which will solve an issue of the changing the phone's time zone.